# Video thumbnail image deleted after closing video ("Done" button"

Tags: iphone, video, uiwebview, youtube, thumbnails

I am working with mp4 videos hosted by my company, not YouTube.

I am using the following code to create a clickable thumbnail in a UIWebView:

```
videoButtonHTML = [videoButtonHTML stringByAppendingFormat:@"<body bgcolor=\"#000000\"><a href=\"%@/\"><img src=\"%@\" width=\"120\" height=\"90\" border=\"0\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"/></a></body>", videoURL, self.imageLink];

[videoButtonWebview loadHTMLString:videoButtonHTML baseURL:nil];
```

This works fine at first.  It creates the thumbnail and plays the video.  The problem is that, when you close the video, the thumbnail image disappears.  I still have the "blank" Quicktime play image.  I really want to keep the image, though.

I've tried this both with and without the shockwave tag - same result.  I found an embedYoutube function in a tutorial.  It works great with YouTube videos, but not with mp4 videos.  Here's that code, in case it helps:

```
- (void)embedYouTube1:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
    [videoView release];
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving the image as `NSData`, maybe to your `NSUserDefaults` *(when the video is loaded)*, then you can display the thumb from **defaults**, instead of the video itself *(when the video is not loaded)*.

Comment: Thanks. However, in which even should I pull my saved data from NSUserDefaults? I put breakpoints in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear, but neither seem to get called when I press "Done" on the video player.